# Maintain xml format in mail in codeigniter

Tags: php, xml, codeigniter, email

I have a mail function in codeigniter which is sending xml data but  in my mail its not showing in proper format
Here in the below code $result contains data in xml format.

```
public function send_mail($id,$result){
    require_once 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mailto = "test@gmail.com";
    $name   = "Testing";
    $content= "Result - $result <br>";
    $subject= "Test Mail - $id : ";

    $mail = new PHPMailer;

        $mail->isSendmail();
        $mail->setFrom('admin@mywebsite.com', 'Tester');           
        $mail->addAddress($mailto, $name);
        $mail->Subject = $subject;
        $mail->msgHTML($content);

    if ($mail->send()) {
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this :

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
...
```